# Re-link an existing $scope?

Tags: angularjs

Let me set some context first; 
I am creating a wizard in angular, with these characteristics:

- The steps in the wizard are big; each step has it's own controller / $scope / template.
- The steps in the wizard are dynamic (step1's output decides whether the next step is step2a or step2b).
- Of course, step-state should be preserved. When stepping back from step2 to step1, the data in the step1 view should still be there.

In my implementation, I've found a lot of inspiration in the codebase for [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).
Basically my approach is:

- When going to a step, create a $scope for this step and use the $controller service to create the controller
- $compile the step-template and link this step-template to the step-$scope

This all works out great.

However, I'm having doubts on my implementation to step back in the wizard:
To achieve this, I'm keeping an array of step-$scope objects for each step that has been taken.

Whenever stepping back (for instance from step2 back to step1), I:

- look up the $scope for step1
- re-$compile the template for step1 and re-link it to the $scope for step1

This seems to work, however:

1. Why can't I just re-use the compiled/linked template from step 1? 
    (this way, I could keep references to the compiled/linked templates, not to the $scopes)
2. Is this re-$compiling / re-linking the right approach to take?

Thanks for your time, 
Koen

Comment: please share more of your code... esp the compiled template call and sample of a template that is compiled

Comment: Hi Dave, I've created a working sample in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZXQY/5/).
The functions of your interest are "invokeStep", where the template/scope for a step are stored; And "showStepInstance" where this state is restored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use routing, using something along the lines

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/wizard/:stepNr', {...})
```

(c.f. AngularJS docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example)

Your "back" and "next" buttons would just be a href like this:

```
<a href="#/wizard/{{scopeVarContainingNumberOfPrevStep}}">Prev</a>
<a href="#/wizard/{{scopeVarContainingNumberOfNextStep}}">Next</a>
```

The Scopes of all steps will have one common $parent. So, Before going to the next step, you could store the important values there:

```
$scope.$parent.stepData[currentStepNr] = $scope.stepData;
```

whenever coming back to a step, the Scope of the left future step is automatically destroyed. All you need to do is

```
$scope.stepData = $scope.$parent.stepData[currentStepNr]; // load from parent scope into current scope
delete $scope.$parent.stepData[currentStepNr]; // discard in the parent scope
```

PS: the fact that the Parent Scope is common to all step scopes is a "special case" So you might want to use a Service for storing the data between steps, as suggested by @Bixi

**EDIT**:  In case, the number of the next step is determined by an external web srevice, you can do (assuming a simple http call)

```
$http.get('/your/service').success(function(responseData){
    /* grab nr of next step from responseData; 
       remember it and 
       use $location.$path to navigate to #/wizard/nextStep.  */ 
    $location.$path('/wizard/' + varContainingNumberOfNextStep);
});
```

Comment: The issue with this approach is that the scopeVarContainingNumberOfNextStep should be known up font. In my case, a web service call is performed on "next". The result of this call determines what the next step is.

Comment: That shouldn't be a big problem. You can do (assuming a simple http call) `$http.get('/your/service') .success(function(responseData){ /* grab nr of next step from responseData; remember it and use $location.$path to navigate to #/wizard/nextStep. */ });`

Answer (score 1):

First, how are you storing your data? For this kind of pattern, the best choice would be a service which stores your steps data. This service will be available through all your steps (controllers).

More information about services: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Next, you're talking about two solutions:

- storing data and letting angular construct the screen from scratch again
- storing fully compiled templates

The first solution is the angular standard behavior. To maintain a as-lightweight-as-possible DOM, angular removes previous ng-view DOM elements and replaces them with the new ones (new route). No problem here, it's angular's work and it does it well.

The second solution is possible. In my view, storing the compiled DOM would be overkill, instead you could just let it loaded in the browser (but showing/hiding its content via CSS)... But there are some disadvantages unlike method #1 (heavyweight DOM).

I think you should let angular construct your steps using only stored data.

Comment: I'm storing the data in the wizard control itself, as shown in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZXQY/5/). You'll notice that the info for all the steps that have been taken are in the "takenSteps" field.

In this field, the scope & the template are stored. When the steps needs to be restored, the template is re-compiled against this scope.

I think this is quite in line with your first option, except I'm not using a service to achieve this, but let the wizard control itself handle this.

Comment: Your whole code seem very complex, maybe you could have use more built-in functionnality of angular like I explained in my first option... But maybe it's needed in your case for more flexibility. It's up to you now ;)

Comment: It does get pretty complex indeed; I almost feel like I'm creating my own router. I will re-consider and see if there's another approach, that leverages the basic angular concepts. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just to have the parent controller with some step flag and make some use of ngInclude capabilities to create new child scope?

```
mod.controller('WizardParentCtrl', function() {
  this.step = '1';
})
```

Outer HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="WizardParentCtrl as WizardParent">
  <div ng-include="'steps/'+WizardParent.step+'.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Inner HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Step1Ctrl as Step1">
...
</div>
```

`WizardParent` will be accessible in the child controllers via scope inheritance, and you can communicate with it in order to save the data or change steps.